# Equations with matrices

Tags: matrices, matrix-equations

[image]

---

**Translation:**

Given the matrices A=.... and B=....

a) Calculate $A^tA$ and $AA^t$, ($A^t$ is the transposed of the matrix $A$)

**b) Calculate $A^{-1}$ (inverse matrix) and resolve the linear system $A$  ... = ....**

c) Calculate $C^2$, where $C = ABA^t$

My question was about point b)

I thought that since

$$A 
\left(
\begin{array}{c}
x\\
y\\
z 
\end{array}
\right) = \left(
\begin{array}{c}
1\\
1\\ 
1
\end{array}
\right)
$$

It could be like:

$AX=B 
(A^{-1})AX=(A^{-1})B
(I)X=(A^{-1})B
X=(A^{-1})B $

But in general I don't know why it's saying that the inverse matrix of A is equal to the matrix A and (x y z) and that is equal to the inverse of matrix A and (1 1 1) so on so on...

I'm having trouble in seeing it so if you can help me it would be great.

EDIT: I can't really write the problem neither the images can be visualized because I don't have reputation. So you would have to copy the link and paste it on your browser.

Comment: If you solved **a)** then do include your work in your question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You already know that $A^T.A=\operatorname{Id}$. But then $A^T=A^{-1}$ and therefore$$A.X=B\iff X=A^{-1}.B\iff X=A^T.B.$$

Comment: Thanks a lot! I think I get it now.

Comment: of course, done done :)